# Spivak's "Calculus in Manifolds" problems

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, vector-analysis

I have some troubles with this problems.

> Problem 1.18: If $A \subset [0,1]$ is the union of open intervals $(a_i,b_i)$ such that every rational number of $(0,1)$ is contained in $(a_i,b_i)$, for some $i$. Prove that ${\partial}A = [0,1] - A$
>
> Problem 3.11: Let be $A$ the set of the problem 1.18. If $\sum_{i=1}^\infty\,(b_i - a_i) < 1$ then ${\partial}A$ does not have measure $0$.

For problem 1.18, I try to find ${\partial}A = \overline{A} \cap \overline{\mathbb{R} - A}$, but I always found that ${\partial}A = [0,1]$, besides I'm not sure if $A = \mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]$.

For problem 3.11, a friend told me that the measure of $[0,1]$ is 1, and $[0,1] - A$ has, also, measure 1 (I don't know when a set has measure 1), and using the hypothesis I have a contradiction, but I don´t see how.

I appreciate all your help. Thanks!!!

Comment: For problem $1.18$ note that $A$ is open, and so $\partial A\cap A=\emptyset.$

Comment: But can I say that if $A$ is open in some space $X$, then ${\partial}A = X - A$. Is that a characterization of an open set?

Comment: With $A = (0,1)$ and $X = \mathbb{R}$, your claim would then be that $\partial A = \mathbb{R} - (0,1)$. Is that true?

Comment: Problem 1.18 implies that $\{0,1\} \subset \partial A$ for all $A$ since $0 \notin A$ and $1 \notin A$ by definition. This makes the statement in 3.11 false.

Comment: No, of course not, that's why I asked if that situation could be possible.

Comment: @user115595: $\partial A = \overline{A} - \mathrm{Int}(A)$ for any $A$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every neighborhood of any point $x\in[0,1]$ contains a rational number since the rationals are dense. Hence, $x$ is an accumulation point of A and $[0,1] \subset \bar{A}=A \cup \partial A.$ Also $\bar{A} \subset [0,1]$. So $A\cup \partial A=[0,1].$ But the intersection of $A$ and $\partial A$ is empty. Therefore $\partial A = [0,1] \setminus A.$

Since $A \cup \partial A = [0,1]$ then $m(A) + m(\partial A) = 1$ because $A$ and $\partial A$ are disjoint.

If

$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}(b_i-a_i)<1,$$

then

$$m(A) = m\big{(}\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}(a_i,b_i)\big{)}\leq\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}(b_i-a_i)<1$$

If it were true that $m(A) < 1$, then $m(\partial A) > 0$ and $\partial A$ could not be a null set.

Comment: This leaves open the problem with 3.11. Is this an error in Spivak, or perhaps of typing the question?

Comment: No, that's what the problem says. I send you a link where you can find the book. (The only problem: the book is in spanish)

http://dibene.files.wordpress.com/2011/04/spivak-calculo-en-variedades.pdf

Comment: If $A \cup \partial A = [0,1]$ then $m(A) + m(\partial A) = 1$ since $A$ and $\partial A$ are disjoint.

Comment: I don't speak Spanish, but doesn't 3.11 say prove that the border of A does *not* have measure $0$?

Comment: You're right Zimul8r, but, as I said, I asked to my teacher this problem on the morning (morning in my place), and he gave me that hint, but you're completely right.

Comment: @user115595: My translation agree with Zimul8r's, and I believe you misunderstood Zimul8r's comment. The question is to show that $\partial A$ does not have measure zero. It is *not* to show that $\partial A$ is the null set. I recommend you edit your OP.

Comment: Oops, apparently "null set" can simply mean a set of measure zero. My apologies!

Comment: Actually, the text seems to ask you to prove that $\partial A$ has measure $>0$, which seemed like the correct question given we're proposing a version of $A$ that cannot logically cover the full measure of $[0,1]$, since that summation implies the measure of $A<1$...

Comment: @user115595 Sorry, misread your comment. We're saying the same thing. ;-)

Comment: OK I reposted my answer -- you got me a bit confused.  But in this example the boundary does not have measure 0.

Comment: Also it is possible to select a countable collection of open intervals that cover the rationals in $[0,1]$ -- for which the measure of the union is less than 1. So the boundary has non-zero measure.